# cassandra query by primary key not working

Tags: cassandra

I am running into a wried problem over querying in Cassandra.

Here is the defination of my table:

```
CREATE TABLE test.ecgs (
uuid timeuuid PRIMARY KEY,
content blob,
filename text,
image blob,
images list<blob>,
page_count int,
thumb blob
) WITH bloom_filter_fp_chance = 0.01
AND caching = {'keys': 'ALL', 'rows_per_partition': 'NONE'}
AND comment = ''
AND compaction = {'class': 'org.apache.cassandra.db.compaction.SizeTieredCompactionStrategy', 'max_threshold': '32', 'min_threshold': '4'}
AND compression = {'chunk_length_in_kb': '64', 'class': 'org.apache.cassandra.io.compress.LZ4Compressor'}
AND crc_check_chance = 1.0
AND dclocal_read_repair_chance = 0.1
AND default_time_to_live = 0
AND gc_grace_seconds = 864000
AND max_index_interval = 2048
AND memtable_flush_period_in_ms = 0
AND min_index_interval = 128
AND read_repair_chance = 0.0
AND speculative_retry = '99PERCENTILE';
```

When I query by:

```
SELECT filename, content FROM ecgs 
WHERE uuid=63dc8442-bf06-11e6-9302-33bde07f6029
```

...from both terminal and script, it shows strange returns.
Firstly the record shows up, but sometimes I cannot filter the record out. And I am sure the data exists in my datacenter.

Here is config of my test datacenter:

```
CREATE KEYSPACE test WITH replication = {'class': 'NetworkTopologyStrategy', 'dc1': '2'}  AND durable_writes = true;
```

Can anybody give me some idea for that?

**Updated at Dec. 27th.**

Here is the status nodetool:

```
Datacenter: dc1
===============
Status=Up/Down
|/ State=Normal/Leaving/Joining/Moving
--  Address        Load       Tokens       Owns    Host ID                                    Rack
UN  192.168.0.102  1.27 GB    256          ?       607bb62d-0bf6-425e-a804-568af02de0bc  rack1
UN  192.168.0.103  1.22 GB    256          ?       988ab168-f3d5-41a4-ab16-200079b3dc17  rack1
```

Comment: Try to specify consistency level ALL and check will it start returning constant result.

Comment: i don't see any table with `ecgs`, in question you have mentioned `pdfs`

Comment: sorry, the pdfs is ecgs. I change the name before post.

Comment: Can you provide nodetool status to see if your nodes are correctly assigned to dc1. Also it may be a problem of consistency. What is your write and read consistency ?

Comment: @DineMartine But isn't consistency in Cassandra about getting the data if enough nodes reply with same data? and in case if query doesn't meet consistency criteria shouldn't it fail in the first place? correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: @pinkpanther Read Consistency Level is how many replicas you want the value before making a decision. Each replica may give a different value but Cassandra does not compare them, it simply returns the most recent one. Doesn't meet consistency means that not enough replicas answer in time (unavailable or timeout).

Comment: @DineMartine thanks, I'm wondering how he could get the results but not with the given partition key. It shouldn't be possible right, since the partition key wouldn't be changed in multiple replicas anyways.

Comment: @DineMartine Pls refer to the result of "Updated at Dec. 27th." in the post.